# Extjs4 GridPanel data is not loading

Tags: extjs, extjs4

When i am using multiple url within proxy for GridPanel,Data is not loaded in the grid but when i open javascript console from crome, it is being load.
i am using below.

```
storename.getProxy().url = 'myurl';
```

How to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share the code how you build you store/model/reader/writer/proxy, grid, columns. It could as simple as you defined your reader wrongly that it can't read your data, or perhaps, the format of your returned JSON is wrong.

Comment: check the mapping of the grid panel columns and the store. Make sure the 'dataIndex' config is correct. And share the code!

Answer (score 1):

i hope after you're setting the proxy

```
    storename.getProxy().url = 'myurl';
```

you load the store again

```
    storename.load();
```

and about the store, does it have an url initially, does it have autoLoad.. just post some code dude!!

Answer (score 1):

i think put **layout: 'fit'** in parent container of GridPanel will solve this issue too.